# Can I use Extra attack to cast two spells

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat, class-feature, multi-classing

I'm a 5th level monk and a level 1 sorcerer and I'm just wondering if I can use the Extra attack from my monk class feature to cast a spell instead of a melee attack.

Answer (score 21):

**No.**

Extra Attack can only be used when taking the *Attack Action.* Spellcasting doesn't use the attack action so you can't use Extra Attack to cast spells.