# What is the highest damage potential (multi-class) for a 5th level character?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization, multi-classing, damage

I'm wondering for my next session what the highest damage potential is for a multi-class character.

**Criteria:**

- 5e PHB material only
- level 5
- single-target damage only
- consistent DPR (damage per round)
- assume all attacks and spells Crit and deal maximum damage
- characters must be multi-classed
- answers must be OK under RAW; no homebrew or questionable interpretations

Comment: I believe this question is still far too broad.  There are 4368 possible multiclass combinations at 5th level.  You're going to need to narrow the scope to make this answerable.

Comment: Naturally you can exclude those that would not have a high damage potential, any that would involve more than two or three classes.

Comment: "...any that would involve more than **two or three** classes."  Which is it?  This is exactly the type of information that needs to be in the question.

Comment: So if a 3/1/1 split would be higher than a 3/2 then it should be considered, that is what the question is, what is the highest potential damage that can be output from a level 5 character without more than 3 classes included. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: I previously answered a similar question ([What is the most DPR possible at level 1?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/77391)), which was MUCH more constrained and only at level 1. Given the amount of options I had to go over in that dumbed-down version, I feel like I can safely agree that this question is much too broad as it currently is.

Comment: @ConnorRundle Like I said before, there are 4368 possible multiclass combinations at level 5.  What you are saying is you expect any answer to go through every permutation and eliminate the ones that don't meet your requirements which are nebulous at best.  This question is currently impossible to answer.

Comment: I apologise for how broad this is, if it is impossible to answer within the definitions provided please do close it and I will ask a more detailed question once I have decided the two classes, and detail the question around that choice.

Comment: This feels like a question that *could* be brute-forced.

Comment: What makes damage "consistent" for a character with limited resources? For example a wizard? Cantrips only?

Comment: @ConnorRundle if 3/1/1 or 3/2 is the criteria, and you narrow it down to two classes, that looks like a far better scope for the question. (Dare I raise the 2/2/1 bogey?)

Comment: It gets even more broad if you start trying to count force multiplier effects. For example, how would you calculate the DPR of effects like Bardic Inspiration and bless?